# JSON - PHP - Reading Key

Tags: php, json

I have the following code below, which I am trying to run to save the key in the json to a PHP varible. However, for some reason it's just not doing anything - although it seems my code is right, any ideas where I am going wrong?

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('url');
$data = json_decode($json,true);

$id = $data['s_id'];


echo($id);

?>
```

and the json from the external URL looks like this

```
[{"s_id":"20063"}]
```

Comment: `$data[0]['s_id']`

Comment: You can always use `print_r($data);` to see the parsed data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an array wrapping the object

```
$id = $data[0]['s_id'];
```